# Unresponsive javascript when using collection_select?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have just started learning rails, html and javascript. I am using a collection_select to allow a user to select other users in the database:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id), :id, :full_name, :prompt => 'Select', :html => { :id => "colleageselect", :onChange => "renderColCal(this)"} %>

<div id = colleaguecal> </div>
```

I have just been trying to test whether onChange works, by using the javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function renderColCal(select){
        alert('this is a test' + select.valueOf() );
        document.getElementById("colleaguecal").innerHTML = "foo"

    }
</script>
```

But changing the `collection_select` value when running the page doesn't do anything? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is that all the javascript that is being executed?

Comment: @Bustikiller yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the generated html if it is what you are expecting.  I don't see any issues with the js although it would be better if it was unobstrusive.  The only thing that may have caused your issue is that you didn't just passed a hash to the html options.  Try

```
f.collection_select :id,
  Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
  :id,
  :full_name,
  { prompt: 'Select' },
  { id: "colleageselect", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" }
```

Comment: This fixed it! Could you explain this to me please?

Comment: you're passing a hash as the last option but it contains only 1 key which is `html`.  If you check the generated html, you'll probably see `html-id` and `html-onChange` attributes for the select.